# How To use Firebase Auth with Firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a flutter application based on [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore)  and  [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth), I **Add user** (blue button) by **Authentication** firebase, and kept the **ID** in the code so that this user is the **administrator**, regular users can create an account by application (email and password), What I want is to make sure the **administrator** is the only one can delete data from the database, while the rest of the users are only allowed to read and write, so I did this:

I changed **roles** in my Cloud Firestore project to this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      allow delete : if request.auth.uid == 'psqxVzX6BvYCuWbajhcEK1QGZOo1';
    }
  }
}
```

Is this true or not, and how can Firebase be sensitive to **uid**?

Maybe my question is how to send the **uid** with the `firestore` request.

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: There is no need to send the id to Firestore as part of the request. It is automatically handled by the Firestore plugin. You could check that out by making a new account and try to delete a document

Comment: I created a new user, were able to delete Document, and this is opposed the rolls

Comment: Thats because your rule is wrong. Sorry, I didn't notice how you wrote your rule but you allowed to read and write if the request is null. By default, write means create, update, and delete. You can test if your rule works in their sandbox

Comment: I appreciate your effort, thank you, but there is (create, update), I am new to Firebase

Comment: Please replace the picture of your rules with the actual rules as text. In general: don't post pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have a `write` rule, that rules allows create, update and delete operations.
2. If you have multiple rules for the same operation, they are OR'ed together.

This means that your `allow read, write: if request.auth != null` allows any authenticated user to create, update and delete any document in the database.

If you only want to allow any authenticated user to create or update a document, but only want the user with that specific UID to delete documents, you have to explicitly name those operations:

```
allow read, create, update: if request.auth != null;
allow delete: if request.auth.uid == 'psqxVzX6BvYCuWbajhcEK1QGZOo1';
```

For full info, see the documentation on [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to delete the document from a user account but failed